# Cast of 'int' to 'CAMediaTimingFunction *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ipad, xcode4.2, ios5

Can anyone please suggest alternative to this line of code so that my code becomes compatible with ARC.

```
[animation setTimingFunction:(CAMediaTimingFunction*)UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That code isn't correct even in MRR (non-ARC). The only reason it's not *crashing* is because `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` happens to have the value of `0` (which becomes `nil` after the cast).

Instead you should be using

```
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

This will do what you're intending to do, except with an actual instance of `CAMediaTimingFunction*`.